# ReactiveForm force asyncValidator to be exec

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validator

I have a form with 3 fields.
`Country`, `City`, `Age`.

I have an asyncValidator on the group, to check if the `City` belongs to the `Country` (the validator will call a service, thats why he is asynchronous...). I display an error if this is false.

And my 3 fields have the Required validation.

My issue is, when I fill out `Country` and `City`, my asyncValidator is not called. He will be called after I fill out the `Age`.

I know asyncValidator are execute after each synchronous validator have the OK's status.

Is there a way to force the asyncValidator to be call before ? Or set required as asyncValidator ?

Comment: I think a way to solve this is to remove the `required` validator on each control and the `required` validator's logic at `FormGroup` level. This way, you can check there when and when not to return an error.